# How to use two JavaScript (.js) files on one website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I created a website for big (Desktop) and small (Mobile) devices. Not only the .css files differ each other but also the .js files in which the animations are saved. My Problem now is, I don't know how to make the browser use the .js file for small devices if the display is small and on the other site the .js file for big devices if the display is big.
Is there any possible solution to use only one webspace with two Java Script files automatically choosen by screen size?

Comment: So you want the browser to use a particular js file depending on the screen size?

Comment: That's what it sounds like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using JQuery you can do something like this:

```js
if ( $(window).width() > 739) {      
  //Add your javascript for large screens here 
} 
else {
  //Add your javascript for small screens here 
}
```

This way you only require one JS file.

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure it is good way or not, but you can also use simple javascript to detect the mobile browser

```
<script>
if( /Android|iPhone|iPad|BlackBerry|IEMobile/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 // include mobile
} 
else {
//include desktop
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
if (screen.width > 768) {
    //keep your desktop js here
}

if (screen.width < 769) {
    //keep your mobile js here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically load a JavaScript file after checking the window size using:

```
var file = window.innerWidth < 800 ? 'small.js' : 'big.js'
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
script.setAttribute('src', file);
```

Answer (score 0):

Testing the user agent is more robust than testing the window width. Here's a library than can help you: [WURFL.io](http://web.wurfl.io/)

Just grab the lib to your page and add:

```
if (WURFL.is_mobile) {
    //add mobiles scripts
}
```